# Logged out of Google in Safari on iOS every time I close it

Tags: ios, safari

I am on iOS 17.1.1. A couple of months ago, I started having a problem wherein when I close Safari and reopen it, or turn my iPhone off and back on, I am logged out of my Google account. I am bot using private mode. I am not using extensions. This only happens with Google and no other site.

How do I fix this?